# Cannot update during an existing state transition, Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Running the code leads to maximum call stack error as well as "Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`." warnings on the browser console thousands of times.

I am new to react, Kindly help me finding the solution. ThankYou :)

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { Button, Form, Grid, Header, Checkbox, Icon, Segment, Image, Divider} from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import Slider from '../Slider';
import {styleDiv} from '../styles';
import {updateEmailRequest, updatePasswordRequest, updateRedirectRequest} from './LoginActions';


class Login extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  handleEmailChange(e){
    this.props.dispatch(updateEmailRequest(e.target.value));
  }

  handlePasswordChange(e){
    this.props.dispatch(updatePasswordRequest(e.target.value));
  }

  handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.mutate({
      variables: { email: this.props.email, password: this.props.password }
    })
      .then(({ data }) => {
        this.props.dispatch(updateRedirectRequest());
        alert("Welcome! " + this.props.email);
      })
  }

  render(){

    return (
      <div>
        <Grid stackable={true} container doubling={true} columns={2}>
          <Grid.Column>
            <Header as="h2">
              Snaphy Labs
            </Header>
            <div style={styleDiv}>
              <Segment textAlign="left">
                <Header as="h4" style={{color:"#D34836"}} >
                  Introducing Automata.
                </Header>
                <p style={{color:"#808080"}}>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                  Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since 1500.</p>
              </Segment>
              <Segment textAlign="left">
                <Header as="h4" style={{color:"#4A90E2"}}>
                  Hello!
                </Header>
                <p>
                  <span>Join Snaphy Labs Now.</span>
                  <span style={{color:"#4A90E2"}}>&nbsp;<a href="/signup"><strong><u>SignUp!</u></strong></a></span>
                </p>
                <Divider/>
                <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
                  <Form.Field required>
                    <label>E-Mail</label>
                    <Form.Input
                      fluid size='medium'
                      icon='user'
                      iconPosition='left'
                      placeholder='E-mail address'
                      type="email"
                      name='email'
                      value={this.props.email}
                      onChange={this.handleEmailChange.bind(this)}
                    />
                  </Form.Field>
                  <Form.Field required>
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <Form.Input
                      fluid size='medium'
                      icon='lock'
                      iconPosition='left'
                      placeholder='Password'
                      type='password'
                      name='password'
                      value={this.props.password}
                      onChange={this.handlePasswordChange.bind(this)}
                    />
                  </Form.Field>
                  <Button color="blue" fluid size='medium'>Login</Button>
                  <br/>
                </Form>
                <Grid columns="equal">
                  <Grid.Column verticalAlign='left'>
                    <Checkbox label='Remember Me' />
                  </Grid.Column>
                  <Grid.Column verticalAlign='right'>
                    <a href="/forgetPassword"><p>Forgot Password?</p></a>
                  </Grid.Column>
                </Grid>
                <br/>
                <a href="/auth/google"><Button color='google plus' fluid size='medium'>
                  <Icon name='google plus' /> Google+
                </Button></a>
              </Segment>
            </div><br/>
            <center>@copyright Snaphy Labs Pvt. Ltd.</center>
          </Grid.Column>
          <Grid.Column>
            <div style={{"margin-top":"55px"}}>
              <Segment.Group horizontal>
                <Segment floated='left'>
                  <Image src='/2.png'/>
                </Segment>
                <Segment floated='left'>
                  <Header as="h4" style={{color:"#4A90E2"}} textAlign="left">
                    Welcome Back! Ravi
                  </Header>
                  <p style={{color:"#808080"}}>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since 1500.</p>
                  <p>Learn More -></p>
                </Segment>
              </Segment.Group>
            </div>
            <div>
              <Slider/>
            </div>
          </Grid.Column>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Retrieve data from store as props
function mapStateToProps(store) {
  return {
    email: store.LoginReducer.email,
    password: store.LoginReducer.password
  };
}


const login = gql`
  mutation($email: String!, $password: String!){
    user{
        login(email: $email, password: $password){
          id
        }
    }
  }
`;


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(graphql(login)(Login));
```

Comment: Admittedly, I can't see what's wrong. If I were you, I would slow take out your event listeners and form submitters until you don't get that error. Then see what's causing the problem.